# sql - find the number of days a user was using the app

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I like to write a sql query that counts the number of days each user used the application and how many concurrent days. A user can enter the app several times a day but that should count as 1.

My table looks like this:

```
id            | bigint 
user_id       | bigint         
action_date   | timestamp without time zone
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to interpret "concurrent" days. Did you mean "consecutive"? Or maybe how many users "concurrently" per day?

Comment: It's also not clear if you want this to be the single longest occurrence of consecutive actions, or a simple counter that counts every time they consecutively used the application.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of days per user:

```
SELECT user_id, count(DISTINCT action_date::date) AS days
FROM   user_action_tbl
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) days_total, SUM(conseq) days_consecutive
  FROM
(  
  SELECT user_id, 
         CASE WHEN LEAD(date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) - date = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END consecutive 
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT user_id, action_date::date date
      FROM table1
     GROUP BY user_id, action_date::date
  ) q
) p
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6bbaf/2)** demo